# We fill numbers in cells of $8\times 8$ table so that the sum of all neighbour cells to given cell is 1. What is the sum of all numbers in the table?

Tags: combinatorics

> We fill numbers in cells of $8\times 8$ table so that the sum of all neighbour cells to given cell is 1. What is the sum of all numbers in the table? Cells are neighbours if they share an edge.

I've started filling the table, but then it started to look messy: [image]

Filling tables $2\times 2$ and $4\times 4$ gives result 2 and 6 and it is easy to see that  $3\times 3$ is impossible to fill in this manner. It would be interesting to see why $n\times n$ table with odd $n$ is impossible
to fill in this way.

Comment: Are diagonals considered “neighbors?”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No.

Comment: If this were a checkerboard, you could solve the problem for each color separately. So if you can put numbers in the black squares such that for every white square, the sum of the neighbors are all -$-1,$ you can fill in the rest of the squares by reflecting the values in the black squares into the white squares.

Comment: The result for a $4\times 4$ is $6$, not $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof <strike>without words</strike> that the sum of all entries is equal to $20$. Consider the below coloring. Each group of the colored groups of squares are the set of neighbors of another square, so the labels of each group must sum to one. There are ten groups, covering half of the squares of the board; a symmetric arrangement covers so the other half.  The board is partitioned into $10\times 2=20$ groups, each summing to one, so the board must sum to $20$.

[image]

Here is a proof with two pictures and several words of why no matrix exists when $n$ is odd, illustrated when $n=7$.

In the left picture, we partition the off-diagonal entries into three groups whose sum is $1$, proving the sum of the off-diagonal entries is $3$. In the right picture, we similarly prove the sum of the off-diagonal entries is $4$. Contradiction!

[image]

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have edited with some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that the marked cells in this figure

[image]

satisfy that its neighbors covers exactly the whole grid (each cell is neighbor of exactly one of the marked cells), so the sum of all numbers is the sum of the neighbors of the marked cells and there are $20$ marked cells so the sum is $20$.

Can you generalize the problem and prove that for a $2n\times 2n$ grid the sum is $n(n+1)$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What candidate configuration? I didn't give any configuration. You should probably read my solution, not just see the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern works, though I would expect there to be more

```
1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

The sum is $20$, and if there is only one possible sum then this is it

More generally, you can say that the sum over the square is equal to $\frac{64}{4}=16$ plus a quarter of the sums on the four edges (so in this example $16+\frac{4+4+4+4}{4}=20$), which is $16$ plus half the sum of the four corners plus a quarter of the sum of values on edges but not corners (so in this example $16+\frac22 +\frac{12}{4}=20$)

Comment: What does that prove?

Comment: @Aqua It gives a sum to aim for